# ListView search widget filter

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview, filter

I'm having trouble finding good tutorials for this. I have a ListView for which I would like to add a 'search' function that would filter the list view according to user input in the search widget found in the action bar.

I have looked through a couple of tutorials and several articles but am unable to wrap my head around the concept. My most recent endeavor was according to [this site](http://software-workshop.eu/content/android-development-creating-custom-filter-listview).

The following is my custom adapter code (please note, it may have unnecessary code due to my attempts in getting it working:

```
package adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.khalid.hisnulmuslim.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import classes.Dua;

public class DuaGroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Dua> implements Filterable {

    /* Filterable things */
    private List<Dua> allModelItemsArray;
    private List<Dua> filteredModelItemsArray;
    private Activity context;
    private ModelFilter filter;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;

    public DuaGroupAdapter(Activity context, List<Dua> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.dua_list_item_card, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.allModelItemsArray = new ArrayList<Dua>();
        allModelItemsArray.addAll(list);
        this.filteredModelItemsArray = new ArrayList<Dua>();
        filteredModelItemsArray.addAll(allModelItemsArray);
        inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        getFilter();
    }
    /* End of Filterable things */

    public DuaGroupAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public DuaGroupAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Dua> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.dua_list_item_card, null);
        }

        Dua p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tvReference = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtReference);
            TextView tvDuaName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDuaName);

            if (tvReference != null) {
                tvReference.setText("" + p.getReference());
            }
            if (tvDuaName != null) {
                tvDuaName.setText(p.getTitle());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    private class ModelFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Dua> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Dua>();

                for (int i = 0, l = allModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    Dua m = allModelItemsArray.get(i);
                    if (m.getGroup().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(m);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.values = allModelItemsArray;
                    result.count = allModelItemsArray.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filteredModelItemsArray = (ArrayList<Dua>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = filteredModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(filteredModelItemsArray.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/duaListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The text required for the filter will be obtained from the Search widget in the action bar. The activity is able to detect when text is input into the search widget text field but it shows nothing; the listView comes up empty, it goes back to the original state once all text is deleted.

The individual rows of the ListView are not that complicated with just two textViews as presented below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReference"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:text="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDuaName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Entering the Bathroom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please help me out? Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you debugged any of your loops to find out if those arrays are getting populated?  where is your getItem and add methods?  Also I believe you might have your notifyDataSetChanged and notifyDataSetInvalidated calls flipped, changed should be called after the data is set for your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped out with this function. The following is the important snippet for setting up a filter:

```
public class DuaGroupAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Dua> mList;    

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // return a filter that filters data based on a constraint
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final ExternalDbOpenHelper helper = ExternalDbOpenHelper.getInstance(mContext);
                final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.openDataBase();

                final List<Dua> duas = new ArrayList<>();
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = db.query(HisnDatabaseInfo.DuaGroupTable.TABLE_NAME, null,
                            HisnDatabaseInfo.DuaGroupTable.ENGLISH_TITLE + " like ?",
                            new String[] { "%" + constraint + "%" }, null, null, null);
                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            final Dua dua = new Dua(c.getInt(0), c.getString(2));
                            duas.add(dua);
                        } while (c.moveToNext());
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }

                final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = duas;
                results.count = duas.size();
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    mList = (List<Dua>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

The full code for the adapter can be found [here](https://github.com/khalid-hussain/HisnulMuslim/blob/master/app/src/main/java/adapters/DuaGroupAdapter.java). Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

1. That website you linked is 3 years old, completely incorrect, and a horrible example. Forget it even exists.
2. Never extend an `ArrayAdapter` if you need a custom implementation of it's filtering logic. There are all sorts of problems when trying to do this.  To include synchronization issues, inability to keep your list and the internal adapter's list in sync, etc. For further reading: [Filtering Problems](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/).

When you need a custom solution for filtering, there are two choices.

1. Write your own adapter from scratch...eg extend the `BaseAdapter`.
2. Use a 3rd party library. [This one](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) in particular was designed to do just what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you,

in fragment

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener()
{ 
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
    { 
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
    {
        mSearchStr = newText;
        if(mSearchStr.isEmpty())
        {
            mContList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            FetchContacts(); 
        }
        else if(mSearchStr.length()>=1)
        {
            mMyListAdapter.getFilter().filter(mSearchStr.toString()); 
        } 
        return true;
    } 
});
```

in adapter.class

```
package com.example.samplephonecontact;

    import java.util.ArrayList;  
    import java.util.HashMap;    
    import com.example.samplephonecontact.ContactListFragment; 
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;  
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;  
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View; 
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;  
    import android.widget.Filter; 
    import android.widget.Filterable;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;  

    public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  implements Filterable
    { 
        private Context mContext;
        private ValueFilter mValueFilter; 
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mContList;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mFilteredContList; 
        HashMap<String, String> mContObj ; 

        public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> PackageList)
        {
                this.mContext = context;
                this.mContList = PackageList;
                this.mFilteredContList = PackageList; 
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return mContList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return mContList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {    
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cont_list, null);

            TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); 
            TextView contactNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number); 
            ImageView contactImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactimage);
            mContObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mContObj = mContList.get(position);  
            String name = mContObj.get("name");
            String number = mContObj.get("number");  
            contactName.setText(name);  
            contactNumber.setText("\t"+number);

            int resid = R.drawable.person1; 
            contactImage.setImageResource(resid);

            return convertView;
        } 
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() 
        {
             if(mValueFilter==null)
             {
                 mValueFilter=new ValueFilter();
             } 
                return mValueFilter;
        } 

        private class ValueFilter extends Filter
        { 
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            { 
                FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filterList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
                if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0)
                { 
                    for(int i=0;i<mFilteredContList.size();i++)
                    {
                        if((mFilteredContList.get(i).get("name").toString().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        { 
                            String name = mFilteredContList.get(i).get("name");
                            String num = mFilteredContList.get(i).get("number");
                            String id= mFilteredContList.get(i).get("id");
                            String numType = mFilteredContList.get(i).get("number_type");
                            String mail = mFilteredContList.get(i).get("mail");
                            String mailtype = mFilteredContList.get(i).get("mail_type");
                            String ch = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                            if(name.toUpperCase().contains(ch))
                            { 
                                HashMap<String, String>  list = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                                list.put("id", id);
                                list.put("name", name);
                                list.put("number", num);
                                list.put("number_type", numType);
                                list.put("mail", mail);
                                list.put("mail_type", mailtype);
                                filterList.add(list);
                            } 
                        }
                    } 
                    results.count=filterList.size();
                    results.values=filterList;
                    ArrayItem ai = new ArrayItem();
                    ai.setMyArrayList(filterList);
                }
                else
                {
                    results.count=mFilteredContList.size();
                    results.values=mFilteredContList;
                } 
                return results;
            } 

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) 
            { 
                mContList=(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) results.values; 
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```